# How can I make my compiler flag an error when trying to compile deprecated OpenGL functions?

Tags: opengl, deprecated, legacy

I learnt to use legacy OpenGl (v1 / 2) around a year back but now I am trying to make something that is a bit more up to date (i.e. >OpenGL 3.3).

I want to use a lot of my old code, however I could really do with the compiler flagging up an error when it tries to compile something legacy (e.g. glBegin() ... glEnd()).

I compiled on a mac a while back and it flagged up this error when trying to compile, but now I'm using a raspberry pi running raspbian.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use-case, you might be able to use the OpenGL ES header instead of the standard OpenGL header. The OpenGL ES header doesn't contain the deprecated functions.

Another possibility would be to use a loader like [gl3w](https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w) which will also make your code more portable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the OpenGL loader generator [glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/) to generate a loader for core profile of the OpenGL version you want to target. The resulting headers will not contain any of the deprected compatibility profile functions and `GLenum` definitions.

However, be aware that this will not catch all deprecated GL usage at compile time. For example, a core profiles mandates that a VAO != 0 is bound when rendering, that vertex arrays come from VBOs and not client-side memory, and a shader program != 0 is used. Such issues can't really be detected at compile time. I recommend to use the [OpenGL Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) functionality to catch those remaining issues at runtime. Most GL implementations will produce very useful error or warning messages that way.